# Can Not Install crossbuild-essential-arm64 On RaspberryPi 4 Model B: Held Broken Packages

Tags: software-installation, apt, raspberry-pi-os, cross-compilation

I am attempting to install `crossbuild-essential-arm64` on my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, running Raspbian. However, I am getting an error saying "you have held broken packages", along with a list of dependencies that can't be installed.

This is the entire output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 crossbuild-essential-arm64 : Depends: gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu (>= 4:8.3) but it is not installable or
                                       gcc:arm64 but it is not installable
                              Depends: g++-aarch64-linux-gnu (>= 4:8.3) but it is not installable or
                                       g++:arm64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When attempting to install the listed dependencies with `apt`, I get a `no installation candidate` error.

I am following the tutorial here: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html

I am attempting to cross-compile the kernel for another RaspberryPi.

Is there a way to install these?

Comment: which version of Raspberry Pi OS are you running?

Comment: @Bravo I’m not sure the exact version, but it was built very recently (I installed it on the as card < 1 month ago)

Comment: `lsb_release -a`

Comment: @Bravo It says `Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)` Release is `10`

Comment: so, not the latest

Comment: @Bravo I was not aware a new os had come out. I have updated it and it seems to work. Thank you :)